# Audited: Associated audits with HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify, acts-as-audited

I've got model `user` and `role`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true

  has_many :roles, through: :users_roles
  has_associated_audits


class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :users_roles
  audited associated_with: :users, join_table: :users_roles
```

When I create a new role, I've got the error:

```
2.4.4 :373 >   User.first.add_role Role.pi, ProjectRequest.find(319)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ProjectRequest Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `project_requests`.* FROM `project_requests` WHERE `project_requests`.`id` = 319 LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`name` = 'pi' AND `roles`.`resource_type` = 'ProjectRequest' AND `roles`.`resource_id` = 319 ORDER BY `roles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `roles` (`name`, `resource_type`, `resource_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('pi', 'ProjectRequest', 319, '2018-06-19 11:40:13', '2018-06-19 11:40:13')
   (54.3ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key' for User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectknowProxy:Class
```

I don't really now whats the problem, did I wrongly specified something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by this tutorial: 
http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

What I did was that I removed the HABTM relation and created model for the joining table.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :users_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_associated_audits


class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :users, through: :users_roles, dependent: :destroy
  audited associated_with: :users

class UsersRole < ApplicationRecord
  # audited associated_with: :role
  audited associated_with: :user

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Now when the audits are created with change at the `UsersRole` instance. 
The problem is that, the change's contains only the `ids` of destroyed columns, so you cannot figure, what it was. 
This problem is partially solved there: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/72#issuecomment-398756380

Answer (score 1):

Look like there is issue with association if it is has_and_belongs_to_many :users and join_table is users_roles on that case in roles table also it should be has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: :users_roles, and this will make HABM relationship.

Comment: Problem is still the same with following definition.
`user` has `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: :users_roles`
`role` has `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :users_roles`

Comment: I hope in RoleUser model having belongs_to :role and belongs_to :user.

Comment: Well with `has_and_belongs_to_many` HABTM the `RoleUser` model does not exists. But when I create it, it works.
I fixed it with removing HABTM by http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/